# Getting rid of wash out rows in R dataframe by group

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
df <- read.table(text='
    CustomerName    Sales          TradeDate
    John           1000              1/1/2015
    John          -1000              1/1/2015
    John           1000              1/1/2015
    John           5000              2/1/2015
    John          -2000              3/1/2015
    John           2000              3/2/2015
    John           2000              3/3/2015
    John          -2000              3/4/2015
    John           2000              3/5/2015
    John           2000              3/6/2015
    John          -3000              4/1/2015
    John           3000              4/1/2015
    John          -3000              4/1/2015
    John           2000              5/1/2015
    John          -2000              5/1/2015
    John           2000              5/1/2015
    Tom            1000              1/1/2015
    Tom           -1000              1/1/2015
    Tom            1000              1/1/2015
    Tom            5000              2/1/2015
    Tom           -2000              3/1/2015
    Tom            2000              3/1/2015
    Tom           -2000              3/1/2015
    Tom            2000              3/1/2015
    Tom            2000              3/1/2015
    Tom           -3000              4/1/2015
    Tom            3000              4/1/2015
    Tom           -3000              4/1/2015
                                             ', header=T)
```

I want to get rid of all the Sales that are equal in amount and opposite in sign(+,-)and only show the remaining net Sales(preferably at the earliest date, but it does not matter either way). My desired data frame looks like this

```
CustomerName    Sales   TradeDate
John            1000    1/1/2015
John            5000    2/1/2015
John            2000    3/3/2015
John            2000    3/6/2015
John           -3000    4/1/2015
John            2000    5/1/2015
Tom             1000    1/1/2015
Tom             5000    2/1/2015
Tom             2000    3/1/2015
Tom            -3000    4/1/2015
```

I chose two 2000s(in John's case in the month of March) from 3/3/2015 and 3/6/2015. But I am also okay with an output that gave me two 2000s at 3/2/2015 or 3/5/2015. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would do, in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# identify how many transactions we need to keep
setDT(df)[,
    n_keep := sum(Sales)/transval
,by=.(CustomerName,transval=abs(Sales))]

# tag those transactions
df[sign(Sales)==sign(n_keep),
    keep := 1:.N %in% tail(1:.N,abs(n_keep[1]))
,by=.(CustomerName,Sales)]

# keep 'em
df[(keep)][,c("n_keep","keep"):=NULL][]
```

which gives

```
   CustomerName Sales TradeDate
1:         John  1000  1/1/2015
2:         John  5000  2/1/2015
3:         John  2000  3/5/2015
4:         John  2000  3/6/2015
5:         John -3000  4/1/2015
6:          Tom  1000  1/1/2015
7:          Tom  5000  2/1/2015
8:          Tom  2000  3/1/2015
9:          Tom -3000  4/1/2015
```

I'm sure my code could be simplified, but I think the steps are pretty transparent.

Comment: There should be two entries for John 2000

Comment: @docendodiscimus Oh you're right. Not sure how to get that... thinking.

Comment: The two columns appear to be a blend of the desired output. Some of activesal should be in transval and vice versa

Comment: @PierreLafortune `transval` is just a helper column used for grouping. Maybe I should remove it at the end. It's for the "transaction value"

Comment: In that case, `activesal` isn't the output because of the two 4000 values.

Comment: That's true, `transval` just needs `activesal`'s sign.

Comment: @Frank Went with a different approach since I wasn't capturing the date. Good idea, though!

Comment: @Frank I changed the example slightly. Would not grouping by  by=.(CustomerName,transval=abs(Sales))]  cause problems when similar amount like 2000 appear in future dates e.g. 5/1/2015 in this example?

Comment: @gibbz00 You can try it and see. I think it's pretty transparent what the code does (computes `n` how many net sales records we have at the end; then takes the `n` most recent records with the right sign). To the extent that you want it to behave differently (and I can imagine scenarios where you would), you'll have to modify the code or choose a different approach.

Comment: @gibbz00 It's the number of records to keep from the tail. I need the `[1]` since I want a single value instead of the whole (repeating) vector.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to just compute daily totals:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(CustomerName, TradeDate) %>%
  summarise(Sales = sum(Sales))
#> Source: local data frame [14 x 3]
#> Groups: CustomerName
#> 
#>    CustomerName TradeDate Sales
#> 1          John  1/1/2015  1000
#> 2          John  2/1/2015  5000
#> 3          John  3/1/2015 -2000
#> 4          John  3/2/2015  2000
#> 5          John  3/3/2015  2000
#> 6          John  3/4/2015 -2000
#> ...
```